# MySQL - Select Register only If its the First Time of the user

Tags: mysql

I have a question, and I don't know if its possible to solve.. I break my mind, and don't discover a solution..

I have a table and I Select the new registers that I don't select last time that the admin has logged in.

No problem.

With this "new registers" I send a gift.

but ONLY if its the FIRST TIME of the user in my website.

(The table is a Training Table - the users made the lesson - register your participation - and If its your first time - I sent a Welcome kit. If he is a returning user, I don't sent the kit again)

LESSON is not sequential (You can make Lesson 2 first)

============================

USERID   LESSON  TIME

222          2    2016-04-01

122         1    2016-04-01

122         3    2015-10-20

In this table I select ALL USERS with TIME = 2016-04-01 (last registers)

============================

USERID   LESSON  TIME

222         2    2016-04-01

122         1    2016-04-01

but.. USERID 122 had made another lesson last year (and receive the welcome kit)

Then, the answer is: (only 222 is a "REAL NEW" user)

============================

USERID  |  LESSON | TIME

222     |    2    |   2016-04-01

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT USERID, LESSON_TIME
FROM REGISTERS AS r1
WHERE LESSON_TIME = '2016-04-01' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM REGISTERS AS r2
                  WHERE r1.USERID = r2.USERID AND 
                        r2.LESSON_TIME < r1.LESSON_TIME)
```

Comment: Hi @Giorgos-Betsos! first of all tks for your time and help.. hum.. I Think this is a great and elegant solution for the problem.. I will test here! (my final table is a little complex than this - but I think the concept is the same..